# Dynamically call all class methods as variables

Tags: python, dynamic

Lets say I have the following files:

#### main.py

```
from foo import SomeClass
```

#### foo.py

```
class SomeClass:
   a = a_object
   b = b_object
```

I want to unpack all `SomeClass` class variables as variables outside the class (in main.py),
So I could call them,

Its possible to do like this:

```
from foo import SomeClass

a = SomeClass.a
b = SomeClass.b
```

But I want to do this dynamically without the need of knowing each class method.

I couldn't think of a neat way to achieve this except `dir()` n `exec()` which is bad, How can I do this?

Comment: I would just use `dir()` and `getattr()`

Comment: @MZ But how would you define variables with same name as class methods outside the class?

Comment: can you explain that a little more? like have `a = ...a` and `b = ...b`?

Comment: @MZ Exactly, like this.

Comment: If you don’t know the name of each class method, how will you know which variables to use later in your program?

Comment: @MarkMeyer Actually `Flask-Migrate` extension reads them when they're defined this way, so when I do this they get read by it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dir()` to get the names, `getattr()` to get the values of those variables, then `setattr()` to set them globally in your own system:

```py
import sys
from foo import SomeClass

curr_mod = sys.modules[__name__]

for var in dir(SomeClass):
    try:
        setattr(curr_mod, var, getattr(SomeClass, var))
    except:
        # some variables can only be assigned to classes
        pass
```